# error node_modules/jest-diff/build/diffLines.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected. in nest js

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs, watch

when i start and run the nestjs app in watch mode using `npm run start:dev`  command
then this error show.

```
ERROR in node_modules/jest-diff/build/diffLines.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/jest-diff/build/diffLines.d.ts(8,34): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/jest-diff/build/index.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/jest-diff/build/index.d.ts(10,34): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/jest-diff/build/index.d.ts(11,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/jest-diff/build/index.d.ts(11,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/jest-diff/build/index.d.ts(11,52): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/jest-diff/build/printDiffs.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/jest-diff/build/printDiffs.d.ts(8,57): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you have to update your `typescript version` with the latest version of typescript in your `package.json` file

in my case, I update with

```
 "typescript": "^3.9.7"
```

Comment: my typescript is  4.1.3 :
and in package.json >  devDependencies  > "typescript": "^3.4.7". I am still facing same issue. any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

If your typescript version is "3.2.4", downgrade jest-diff to version 25.5.0. This will fix the issue.
`npm i jest-diff@25.5.0`

Comment: 1 year later still the same issue, hopefully this gets fixed soon